# Attempt to compare nil with number on object.x coordinate

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I you all, when I try to reload a scene in CORONA SDK using the director class, I get "Attempt to compare nil with number" on

```
if vec.x < _W/2-180 then
```

where vec is

```
local vec = display.newImage("main_char.png", _W/2-180, _H/2+300)
vec.x = _W/2-180
vec.y = _H/2+300
localGroup:insert(vec)
```

I sincerely I haven't find out how to solve it.

Comment: Still no luck? Any update.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I can't see any typos, and the code is indicating that `vec.x` is nil (`vec` is not nil since the error would be attempt access global vec nil, and `_W` is not nil because the error would say attempt to perform arithmetic on nil. Can't see anything wrong with what you show, so cause is in code not shown.

I would `print(type(vec.x))` anywhere that you access `vec.x` (after you set it, after you insert it in localGroup, just before your condition check): search for all places where `vec.x` is set, one of them must be setting it to something nil (like vec.x = `someFunction(...)` and `someFunction` returned `nil`).

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake in typing the question, i use vec.x instead vex.x. Anyway I even if I use another name (i.e. player) it still not work